# Default compiler from llvm-clang to llvm-gcc42 (command line)

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, command-line, clang

I'm trying to compile a project from the command line. The default compiler LLVM-clang and i need to compile with LLVM-gcc42. Switching a compiler in Xcode is really easy. However, on command line it seems to be more problematic. To my understanding "/usr/bin/cc" and "/use/bin/gcc" are used for pointing c/c++ compilers. I noticed that "cc" was linked to "clang" in same directory. So, i changed "cc" to point at "gcc". Did not helped. When i run

`$ gcc -v`

i get response

`Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`

`Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)`

`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0`

How do i change the clang to gcc?

My setup is:

MAC OS X 10.8.5

Xcode 4.6.2

Command line tools

**EDIT 13.02.2014**

The project is a QT project which uses mixture of third party c/c++ libraries. My task is to write a new objective C lib to it. The project is build with `-spec macx-g++` parameter. The configuration scripts can be found `/QTROOT/mkspecs/macx-g++` and `/QTROOT/mkspecs/common`. In `g++-base.conf` key variables are defined as:

`QMAKE_CC = gcc`

`QMAKE_CXX = g++`

Comment: How is the project compiled - i.e. where does it get what compiler to use from in its makefile or other build script

Comment: Closers not this is about development tools so is on topic here and not on SuperUser, However I suspect we need more information otherwise it will be closed as not enough information

Comment: Okay, i will add more details. The project is bit complex. So, i deliberately tried to keep my question simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing links which can affect other programs use the full path to the llvm executables in your build script

e.g. if you have installed the command line tools

```
QMAKE_CC = /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2

QMAKE_CXX = /usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, nailed the problem. Solution was simple. I deleted the old links from `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` and created new ones pointing to the proper compilers.

`gcc -> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2`

and

`g++ -> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2`